# Need help coding Hangman

Tags: java, arrays

This is my code for hangman for my Computer Science final. I need help figuring out how to tell players to choose a different letter if they guess a letter that has already been guessed. Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class HangmanJava
{
    public static void main(String[] args)             
    {
        String input;
        boolean NotFullMan = true;                    
        char guessedLetter = ' ';                          
        Scanner hm = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the hangman word");
        input = hm.nextLine();                          
        List<String> letterGuesses = new ArrayList<String>();

        char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();             
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(input.length());          
        int totalCorrect = 0;     

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
            buffer.append('_');

        while (NotFullMan){
            System.out.println("Enter a letter");
            guessedLetter = hm.nextLine().charAt(0);         
            int correct = 0;

            for (int i=0; i < charArray.length; i++){                
                if(guessedLetter == charArray[i] && buffer.charAt(i) == '_'){ 
                    correct++;
                    totalCorrect++;                         
                    buffer.setCharAt(i, guessedLetter);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("You got " + correct + " correct!");
            System.out.println(buffer.toString());

            if (letterGuesses.contains(guessedLetter)){
                System.out.println("Letter already chosen. Please pick another.");
            }
            else {
                letterGuesses.append(guessedLetter);
            }

            if (totalCorrect == input.length()){
                System.out.println("You win!");
                return;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the guessed letter to your list of previous guesses. Additionally, your list of previous guesses should probably be `List<Character>` instead of `String` so you can do direct adds and compares with your guessed character input.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of letterGuesses to ArrayList and then change append to add, as shown below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class HangmanJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        boolean NotFullMan = true;                    
        char guessedLetter = ' ';                          
        Scanner hm = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the hangman word");
        input = hm.nextLine();                          
        List<Character> letterGuesses = new ArrayList<Character>();


        char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();             
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(input.length());          
        int totalCorrect = 0;     

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)           
            buffer.append('_');

        while (NotFullMan)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a letter");
            guessedLetter = hm.nextLine().charAt(0);         
            int correct = 0;

            for ( int i=0; i < charArray.length; i++)
            {                
                if(guessedLetter == charArray[i] && buffer.charAt(i) == '_')
                { 
                    correct++;
                    totalCorrect++;                         
                    buffer.setCharAt(i, guessedLetter);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("You got " + correct + " correct!");
            System.out.println(buffer.toString());

            if (letterGuesses.contains(guessedLetter))
            {
                System.out.println("Letter already chosen. Please pick another.");
            }
            else 
            {
                letterGuesses.add(guessedLetter);
            }


            if (totalCorrect == input.length())   
            {
                System.out.println("You win!");
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!!

Comment: If this answer is the one you chose, could you please accept it as the answer?